# Show button to another page using cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-cocoon

I am using cocoon on one of forms and i want to add a show button to each row which will direct users to another model's show page. However, while everything is working smoothly i can not make this button to show up.

So this my current view:

```
<div class = "nested-fields">
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class= "table table-hover">
      <tr>
       <th> Product ID </th>
       <th> Button </th>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> <%=f.object.product_id%> </td>
       <td> <%= link_to 'Show', product_path(f.object.product_id), class: "btn btn-outline-success", target: :_blank %> </td>  
      </tr>    
      </table>  
    </div>
</div>
```

When i try to open this page, i am getting this error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]

However, i know that product_id is not nill because, on the table i can print the product_id for each line.  And, my product routes are definitely fine, i can already use them including with show action. And i know that product_id has a matching id in products table.

Also, if try to go to products' index page by using:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', products_path(f.object.product_id), class: "btn btn-outline-success", target: :_blank %>
```

the following url is going to be generated:

> http://localhost:3000/products.97

I just cannot understand why it cannot get the id when i use it product_path.

Any help will be regarded.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this question related to cocoon? Is the "partial" you show also used when rendering the `link_to_add_association`? Or are you only rendering saved items where you know the `product_id` is filled in?

Comment: Hey nathanvda, I am only rendering the saved items. So, i am not trying to add any record but i  want to edit them.

Comment: Did you try either `product_path(id: f.object.product_id)` or `product_path(f.object.product)` (assuming you have defined that association).

Comment: Nathanvda, associations are fine but (f.object.product) does not work as well ass (id: f.object.product_id). Also, i have tried (:id => f.object.product_id) but result was same.

Is there any way to set a parameter in controller level end then use it in my view?

like product_path(@productid) 
the parameter will be setted at parent forms controller in edit action?

Comment: Sorry for the flood but i have just tried to put an same kind of button to another child form but the result is the same.

Comment: Debugging time: if you remove the link/button from the partial, do you see the id's? How are your routes for product defined? What is the output from `rake routes | grep product' ?

Comment: I can see the id's when i remover the link. and this is the route for the product's show action: 
GET    /products/:id(.:format)

Comment: Ok. If the routes are fine, the association is defined, then: are you really really really sure there is not one item in the list that has a `product_id` equal to nil? I added an answer to would render your view a little more robust. Otherwise: could you share a github or something so I could have a look?

Answer (score 0):

From the conversation/comments I can only conclude one of the items `product_id` is actually really nil. Easy way to make sure your table/page still renders is write your view as follows

```
 <td> 
   <% if f.object.product_id.present? %>
     <%= link_to 'Show', product_path(id: f.object.product_id), class: "btn btn-outline-success", target: :_blank %> 
   <% end %>
 </td>
```

Comment: Hello nathanvda,

Actually yesterday i have tried something else to see if the product_id is really nill. 

The below line worked perfectly fine but i do not know how convenient this approach is: 


`<%= link_to 'Show', "http://localhost:3000/products/#{f.object.product_id}", class: "btn btn-outline-success", target: :_blank %> `

Comment: Mmmm that should be identical? That seems to suggest something is wrong with your routes? How is your routes for product defined? You never showed that? Also the output for `rake routes | grep product` --is should have the `product` in front for the `product_path` to work. But on the other hand: great you found a working solution :)